# Converting .wav audio files to .h5 (hdf) files using SciPy and PyTables

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, speech-recognition, wav, hdf

I need to convert audio .wav files to the .hf or the .npz format, as they are the supported format for training speech translation systems with FBK-Fairseq-ST (https://github.com/mattiadg/FBK-Fairseq-ST).
The following script is meant to run from terminal as  `python script.py /path/file.wav` and write a new hdf file storing the information of the .wav file in the same folder.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import tables
import numpy
import sys

#read data from wav
#fs, data = wavfile.read('/home/vittoria/Documents/corpus-test/01.wav')
fs, data = wavfile.read(sys.argv[1])

#ouput
folder=sys.argv[1][:-6]
name= sys.argv[1][-6:-3]+"h5"

#save_to acoular h5 format
acoularh5 = tables.open_file(folder+name, mode = "w", title = name)
acoularh5.create_earray('/','time_data', atom=None, title='', filters=None, \
                         expectedrows=100000, chunkshape=[256,64], \
                         byteorder=None, createparents=False, obj=data)
acoularh5.set_node_attr('/time_data','sample_freq', fs)
acoularh5.close()
```

However, it raises a value error: **ValueError: the shape ((0,)) and chunkshape ((256, 64)) ranks must be equal.**

input from terminal: 
`python 2hf.py 01_83.wav"` (python script.py relative-file-path)

Traceback error, please notice that in "environments/hdf/lib/python3.6/" "hdf" is the root folder of the virtual environment. "/tables/" is the folder for the package tables 3.6.1 (https://pypi.org/project/tables/) installed via the pip command in the virtual environment.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2hf.py", line 18, in <module>
    byteorder=None, createparents=False, obj=data)
  File "/home/giuseppe/environments/hdf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/file.py", line 1384, in create_earray
    track_times=track_times)
  File "/home/giuseppe/environments/hdf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/earray.py", line 160, in __init__
    track_times)
  File "/home/giuseppe/environments/hdf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tables/carray.py", line 212, in __init__
    (shape, chunkshape))
ValueError: the shape ((0,)) and chunkshape ((256, 64)) ranks must be equal.
Closing remaining open files:01_83.h5...done
```

Comment: Since I am also trying to teach myself acoular (https://github.com/acoular/acoular) the script above tryes to replicate the conversion to the h5 acoular format as in this link https://github.com/acoular/acoular/issues/25

Comment: What is `data.shape`?   Is there more of the error message that you didn't include?  If so, add the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback) to the question.

Comment: Thanks, I made an edit to the question so as to include the complete error message

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it by changing the script this way

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import tables
import numpy
import sys

#read data from wav
#fs, data = wavfile.read('/home/vittoria/Documents/corpus-test/01.wav')
fs, data = wavfile.read(sys.argv[1])

#ouput
folder=sys.argv[1][:-6]
name= sys.argv[1][-6:-3]+"h5"

#save_to acoular h5 format
acoularh5 = tables.open_file(folder+name, mode = "w", title = name)
acoularh5.create_earray('/','time_data', atom=None, title='', filters=None, \
                         expectedrows=100000, \
                         byteorder=None, createparents=False, obj=data)
acoularh5.set_node_attr('/time_data','sample_freq', fs)
acoularh5.close()
```

I basically just removed this part `, chunkshape=[256,64]` :-)

Hope this helped.